# Using Sample_weight on test set

Tags: testing, scikit-learn, xgboost, imbalanced-data

I am using XGBoost for an imbalanced dataset ( ratio of positive samples to negatives is 1/14). I used the sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_sample_weight to set sample_weight parameter.

To report the results on test data to my team, I did the same and calculated precision_score and recall_score with sample_weights calculated on the test data.

However I feel that the resulting values tend to be very optimistic this way. especially the precision value which is important to us is way higher when using weights.

So was wondering if I should be using the weights on test data at all or it is supposed to be used only for training and hyperparameter tunning purposes?